# Keras model spills out unknown error | (IndexError: list index out of range)

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I'm creating a CNN discriminator model to validate audio for a [gan](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generative_Adversarial_Networks). It takes the output tensor from the generator part of the gan. But for some reason I'm getting this weird error which doesn't even specify the line number, when using the compiled model with audio tensor from the generator.

**Code:**

```
def build_audio_discriminator(audio_shape, num_classes):

    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=(2), padding="same", input_shape=audio_shape))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=(2)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Dense(128))

    model.summary()

    audio_shape_ = (None, audio_shape[1])
    audio = Input(shape=audio_shape_)

    # Extract feature representation
    features = model(audio)

    # Determine validity and label of the image
    validity = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(features)
    label = Dense(num_classes+1, activation="softmax")(features)

    return Model(audio, [validity, label])


# Build and compile the discriminator
#audio_shape: (31, 214161), num_classes: 1
audio_discriminator = build_audio_discriminator(audio_shape, num_classes)
audio_discriminator.compile(loss=losses, optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['accuracy'])

# audio: Tensor("model_4/sequential_4/activation_4/Softmax:0", shape=(?, 214161), dtype=float32)
audio_valid, audio_target_label = audio_discriminator(audio)
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 103, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 91, in main
    audio_valid, audio_target_label = audio_discriminator(audio)
  File "C:\Users\MrGrimod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py", line 603, in __call__
    output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\MrGrimod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py", line 2061, in call
    output_tensors, _, _ = self.run_internal_graph(inputs, masks)
  File "C:\Users\MrGrimod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py", line 2212, in run_internal_graph
    output_tensors = _to_list(layer.call(computed_tensor, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\MrGrimod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 546, in call
    return self.model.call(inputs, mask)
  File "C:\Users\MrGrimod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py", line 2061, in call
    output_tensors, _, _ = self.run_internal_graph(inputs, masks)
  File "C:\Users\MrGrimod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\topology.py", line 2212, in run_internal_graph
    output_tensors = _to_list(layer.call(computed_tensor, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\MrGrimod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\convolutional.py", line 156, in call
    dilation_rate=self.dilation_rate[0])
  File "C:\Users\MrGrimod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 3151, in conv1d
    data_format=tf_data_format)
  File "C:\Users\MrGrimod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_ops.py", line 750, in convolution
    name=name, data_format=data_format)
  File "C:\Users\MrGrimod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_ops.py", line 796, in __init__
    input_channels_dim = input_shape[num_spatial_dims + 1]
  File "C:\Users\MrGrimod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py", line 521, in __getitem__
    return self._dims[key]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: you mention `IndexError` but I don't see that in the stack trace, can you include it?

Comment: ups, sorry didn't notice, it was cut off while copying. sry! changed it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to reshape input Tensor to proper Conv1D input shape: (-1, 214161, 1)

```
audio = tf.reshape(audio, [-1, 214161, 1])
```

The solution shown above lets you run into a problem though, because the object returned by tf.reshape is not a Keras tensor but a standard tensor without *_keras_history* flag. My recommendation is to add:

```
model.add(Reshape((214161, 1)))
```

instead the solution above to your model.